# Filled textbox depending on user choice

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list

I need to create leave list in Sharepoint. The problem is, that one of requirements says that, if user pick "maternity leave", in textbox should appear text: "Child's name: \nChild's age: ". Is that possible to implement that logic in Sharepoint?

**Example**:

Possible choices: vacation leave, sick leave, maternity leave etc.

If user select vacation leave/sick leave, there is blank textbox, which user can fill (already have that)

If user select maternity leave, in textbox appears text, which user can edit (the problem)

I'm new to sharepoint, so please be forgiving.
Also it's my first question here, so "Hello SP World!" :)

Comment: Would you please confirm which version of SharePoint are you using, Online or Server? You can check out the reference here if you don't know how to identify: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/which-version-of-sharepoint-am-i-using-3575ff57-037f-48cf-9398-99080c34b25f

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder ahead, the task would be a bit complicated for a new user to SharePoint.

Different options are available based on the version of SharePoint you are using:

1. For **SharePoint Server**, you can customize the list form using **InfoPath**. Apply rule to the Text column control so that it returns the demanded texts when condition is met.

   References: [Customize a SharePoint list form.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-a-sharepoint-list-form-c1f9283d-f704-4bbe-a8aa-827425ab31ae) / [Add rules for performing other actions.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-rules-for-performing-other-actions-5322d726-b787-4e5f-8d37-ba6db68b451d)
2. For **SharePoint Online**, you can use **Column formatting** to return specific values on condition. But the texts are not kept while user typing, they act more like screen tips this way.

   Reference: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#apply-conditional-formatting)